# How can selecting an image in my UI stop my Web API?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In Visual Studio 2019, I start my .NET Core 3 Wep API. It runs and accepts requests.

Then, in my Angular UI, I have a new section to choose a file. If I click that, then choose a file, or hit cancel in the open dialog, my Web API app shuts down. I'm trying to understand how that's possible. I'm only doing front-end stuff. There are no network calls being made.

Here is the screenshot of what I click.

[image]

When I hit cancel, my Web API stops. I can see in VS that my run button is enabled again, like it's ready to be started once more.

On the front end, this is all that's happening:

```
<label class="image-upload-container btn btn-bwm" style="float: left;">
    <input #imageInput
           type="file"
           accept="image/*"
           (change)="processFile(imageInput)">
</label>
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'selectedImage'}">
</div>
```

This is the `processFile()` function:

```
  processFile(imageInput: any) {
    // https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-image-upload-easy-with-angular-1ed14cb2773b/
    console.log('in process file');
    //this.selectedImage = imageInput;
  }
```

You can see that there is only a call to log something. In dev tools, there is no network call or console error. How does selecting a file (or hitting cancel in the open dialog) cause my back end service to stop? I'm not even sure what to check.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `(change)="processFile(imageInput)"` -- did you mean `(change)="processFile($event)"`? I'm not much of an Angular dev, but I've only ever used filters or `$event` there.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy. I'll keep that in mind to try after getting through this issue. What's weird is that my Web API just does. I even have VS set to break on all exceptions. And my logging middleware isn't getting hit.

Comment: I'm wondering if that *is* the issue. Try changing it to `$event` and see if that fixes it. Your *browser* may be crashing which is ending your debug session.

Comment: I actually did try it. Same result. Browser isn't crashing.

Comment: Hmm ok -- Super odd. What if you open a new browser instance and go to the page? Basically, does it still do that if you execute the action outside of the debug session from a new browser instance?

Comment: I've been using Brave and having the issue. I just tried it in Chrome and the problem doesn't happen. I don't get it. But thanks for the suggestion. That may allow me to at least continue with Chrome now.

Comment: I wonder what happens when you use Brave browser with "Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects -> Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops" disabled. Does the issue still occur?

Comment: @Nathan When I do your suggestion, the problem no longer occurs. Can you explain why? Is it because the open dialog window gets closed, so VS thinks the entire UI was closed and debugging stops?

Comment: I have no explanation as to why it happens. Does the browser stay open after you close the dialog window? You can try to turn the setting back on and change web browser inside VS to Chrome and see if the issue still happens. If not, I'd assume it's an issue with Brave.

Comment: Yes, the browser stays open after I close the dialog window. I turned the setting back on, changed VS to use Chrome, and now the issue doesn't happen at all, either in Brave or Chrome. If you'd like to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll approve. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, glad the issue is solved! I posted my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the issue occurs, but you can try this in Visual Studio:

Turn off `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects -> Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops` to see if this fixes the issue.